# Turn NumPy Array of characters into a string

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, chars

I have a numpy array of characters and when I write it to file it writes as:

```
['K' 'R' 'K' 'P' 'T' 'T' 'K' 'T' 'K' 'R' 'G' 'L']
```

I want it to write with just the letters and without the brackets or quotations i.e. as:

```
KRKPTTKTKRGL
```

I have looked at numpy documentation and from what I have gathered the solution is a chararray however it looks like this is not as functional as a normal array.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `tostring()` method of `numpy` as:

```
>>> st = np.array(['K' 'R' 'K' 'P' 'T' 'T' 'K' 'T' 'K' 'R' 'G' 'L'])
>>> st.tostring()
'KRKPTTKTKRGL'
```

Since you have a `numpy` array, this method will be faster than `join()`.

For Python3x `tostring()` can be used as:

```
>>> st = np.array(['K','R','K','P','T','T','K','T','K','R','G','L'])
>>> st.astype('|S1').tostring().decode('utf-8')
'KRKPTTKTKRGL'
```

Comment: In Python 3 (don't know about 2) this creates a bytes object, not a string. Note that the OP's array will probably contain commas in the definition, as otherwise it is effectively `np.array(['KRKPTTKTKRGL'])`. I suspect the lack of commas is simply because that's what OP says is printed to a file. See the docs [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html) for more details.

Comment: I am using Python 2, this method worked perfectly. It did exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Note that tostring() is deprecated since numpy version 1.19.0, tobytes() does the same (it has always returned a bytes object)

Answer (score 9):

If you just have a numpy array then why not convert it to a string directly for writing to your file? You can do this using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) which accepts an iterable (list, numpy array, etc).

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(['K', 'R', 'K', 'P', 'T', 'T', 'K', 'T', 'K', 'R', 'G', 'L'])

s = ''.join(arr)
# KRKPTTKTKRGL
```

Comment: If you could explain the downvote, I'd be happy to edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In a numpy way, you can do:

Using F-String *(Only available for Python 3.4+)*

```
s = arr.view(f'U{arr.size}')[0]
```

Using the default string:

```
s = arr.view('U' + str(arr.size))[0]
```

In both, we convert the array into a usable [unicode *(check the `kind` attribute at page bottom)*](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html) format of the size of the array.

Which is the [`dtype`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dtype.html?highlight=numpy%20ndarray%20dtype#numpy.ndarray.dtype) of the string if you try to convert it to [`numpy.array`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.array.html?highlight=numpy%20array#numpy.array)

```
In[15]: import numpy as np
In[16]: arr = np.array(['KRKPTTKTKRGL'])
In[17]: arr.dtype
Out[17]: dtype('<U12')
```

Note: it works with non-English letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
"".join(['K' 'R' 'K' 'P' 'T' 'T' 'K' 'T' 'K' 'R' 'G' 'L'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [`tofile()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) method to save the array to file, the default separator is the empty string `""`.

So if your array is this,

```
st = np.array(['K', 'R', 'K', 'P', 'T', 'T', 'K', 'T', 'K', 'R', 'G', 'L'])
```

then if you're using Python 2,

```
>>> st.tofile('myfile.txt')
```

creates a file with the following content:

```
KRKPTTKTKRGL
```

If you're using Python 3, you may need to explicitly cast the array to the `S` string type first:

```
>>> st.astype('|S1').tofile('myfile.txt')
```