# Concatenate elements of an array with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i'm working with python/numpy and search in the docs but cant find the method to accomplish this

i have this two arrays and want to concatenate the elements inside the array into a second array

this is my first array

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

my goal is

Output:

`[[00000000], [00000000]]`

the reason of this is for later transform every element of the array into hex

Comment: What exactly is `00000000`?  A string of '0' characters?  An integer?

Comment: @hpaulj is an string

Comment: Why didn't you write it that way? How about `a `?

Comment: the code pasted is for clarification, the firt array comes from an image loaded with pillow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [100]: a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [101]: a
Out[101]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [102]: a.astype(str)
Out[102]: 
array([['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']], dtype='<U11')
In [103]: a.astype(str).tolist()
Out[103]: 
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
In [104]: [''.join(row) for row in _]
Out[104]: ['00000000', '00000000']
```

Answer (score 1):

A more concise, pure numpy version, adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27572301):

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: row.astype('|S1').tostring().decode('utf-8'),
                    axis=1,
                    arr=a)
```

This will create an array of unicode strings with a maximum length of 8:

```
array(['00000000', '00000000'], dtype='<U8')
```

Note that this method only works if your original array (a) contains integers in range 0 <= i < 10, since we convert them to single, zero-terminated bytes with `.astype('|S1')`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this approach:

```
import numpy as np

a =  np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

b =  np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

#concatenate 
concat=np.concatenate((a,b))

#reshape
print(np.reshape(concat,[-1,8]))
```

output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: This is not actually a solution. Print just doesn't show the commas separating the elements of the first axis.