# Merging strs in a numpy array - what's the most effective way?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, string-operations

Let's say I have an array

```
arr = np.array([['a ', 'b ', 'c'], ['d ', 'e ', 'f']])
```

and I want to turn it into

```
[['a b c'], ['d e f']]
```

using only vectorized operations. What's the most efficient way of doing it?

Comment: You can try a combination of `for loops` and `join()`.

Comment: If mentioning the most efficient, what are the ways you tried?

Comment: Also *NumPy* is fast for numbers, I don't know about strings, it might not be suitable here. Anyway, check https://stackoverflow.com/q/49788027/4788546.

Comment: `numpy` doesn't add anything to a pure list and string operation: `[''.join(i) for i in arr.tolist()]`.  Feel free to do your own timings on realist sized arrays.  `np.char` has some functions that apply string methods to elements of arrays, but I haven't anything that works fpr this.  Plus those functions don't offer any speed benefits.

Comment: I had done a simple for loop:
```
for triple in str_triples:
    triple = ' '.join(triple)
    pre_processed.append(triple)
```
I only tried it in a small amount of data (about 30k rows), but I need it to work in potentially millions of rows, so I was a bit wary of just using a for loop for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your array values to python's `object` type to infer further string addition with `np.sum` operation:

```
arr = np.sum(arr.astype(object), axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

---

```
[['a b c']
 ['d e f']]
```

Comment: What a great solution, thank you! Could something like this be used here?

arr_triples = train.triples
column1 = np.char.add(arr_triples[:,:2], ' ')
column2 = arr_triples[:, 2:]
str_triples = np.concatenate((column1, column2), axis=1).astype('str')
del arr_triples
del column1
del column2

Where arr.triples is of shape (30000, 3), but the string in each of the first two columns does not have a space (therefore why I use char.add()). Ideally I would like not to have to create a new variable for the first two columns, one for the third one and concatenate them together.

Comment: @Kliker, welcome. It's not clear what are the actual values of ` arr_triples` and the final expected result from the comment you left; - that could be moved to a separate question

Comment: If the data is actually in a `pandas` database, look at `pandas` own string handlers.  For a start, it uses python strings, not numpy ones.  I don't know if its faster, but numpy's handling of string is not fast.